# How to receive Message of subscribed Topic with Moscapsule

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mqtt

I want to develop an iOS App that can publish and subscripe to Topics, and can also read the messages. I'm using the Moscapsule Libaray. 
When I publish an Message to the Topic, everything works fine.
Also I know that it subscriped to the Topic. 
But I don't know how to get the Message of the subscribed Topic.

so subscribe to the Topic I use :

```
 let mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "cid", host: "test.mosquitto.org", port: 1883, keepAlive: 60)

 let mqttClient = MQTT.newConnection(mqttConfig)

 mqttClient!.subscribe("doorlight", qos: 2)
```

the Logging Output also show me that it is subscribed to the Topic, cause it writes this Log into the Debug Area. Also I can see that it counts the right size of Bytes. But I don't know how to get the message.

```
2016-03-29 17:19:01.666 TestApp[1031:17724] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client cid sending PUBLISH (d0, q2, r0, m1, 'doorlight', ... (7 bytes))
```

I dont Log the File in my Code, and also I think it gets Logged in the Code of the Framework, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this after you subscribe:

```
 print (mqttConfig.onMessageCallback)
```